# Android in app purchase where to register receiver

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've tried the sample project from Google-Trivial Drive

it works well now I'm trying to refactor it

see the comment in the link below

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/MainActivity.java#L198

it says, "We register the receiver here instead of as a  in the Manifest" also "registering this listener in an Activity is a bad idea"

so what should I do actually?

Answer (score 0):

I suffered through number of queries while dealing with google-trivial drive sample for version 3

I found something easy to use and lightweight interface to deal with latest version. Go through below lib :

[InApp Billing V3](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)

Comment: Is it safe not to use backend server for acknowledging purchases? I prefer not to use the server. Do you have any suggestion how to make it secured?